# Axios gives an error: Cannot read property '$get' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

github code: https://github.com/aurora10/amazone-clone.git

I try to utilize Axios to hit an API but get an error:

The error in console is NUXT SSR:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$get' of undefined
at asyncData (pages/index.js:98:35)
at promisify (server.js:1898:15)
at Promise.all.Components.map.Component (server.js:1573:82)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at module.exports../.nuxt/server.js.__webpack_exports__.default (server.js:1569:51)
```

This is how I try to do it:

```
export default {

async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  try {
    let response = await $axios.$get("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
    console.log(response);
    return {
      products: response.products
    };
  }catch (err) {

    console.log(err);

  }
}
```

}

The API itself works. If I call it from browser - it gives me the list of products.
What am I doing wrong?

Complete fille:

```
<template>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid browsing-history">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-sm-8 col-8">

      <h1 class="a-size-large a-spacing-none a-text-normal">All products</h1>
      <div class="a-spacing-large"></div>

      <a href="#" class="a-button-buy-again">Add new product</a>
      <a href="#" class="a-button-history margin-right-10">Add new category</a>
      <a href="#" class="a-button-buy-again margin-right-10">Add new owner</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a-spacing-large"></div>

<div class="container-fluid browsing-history">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 br bb">

      <div class="history-box">
        <!--          product page-->
        <a href="#" class="a-link-normal">
          <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </a>

        <div class="a-spacing-top-base asin-title">
        <span class="a-text-normal">
          <div class="p13n-sc-truncated">Title </div>
        </span>
        </div>

        <div class="a-row">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
          </a>
          <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
          <span class="a-color-tertiary a-size-small asin-reviews">(1732)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--price-->
      <div class="a-row">
        <span class="p13-sc-price">$25</span>
      </div>
      <!--byttons-->
      <div class="a-row">
        <a href="#" class="a-button-history margin-right-10">Update</a>
        <a href="#" class="a-button-history margin-right-10">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

export default {

    async asyncData({$axios}) {
      try {

        let response = await $axios.$get("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
        console.log(response);
        return {
          products: products
        };
      } catch (err) {

        console.log(err);

      }
    }
  };

I did make sure it is installed. I had also included

```
module.exports = {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  axios: {
    // proxyHeaders: false
  }
}
```

just like they tell in the the installation manual. Also tried to remove $ before get...still the same error in console:(  I have no clue what else could be wrong..

Comment: Where is asyncData being called? You may be calling it multiple times by accident and it's passing a undefined value

Comment: It is being called only in in index.vue file. The only place I used it. see above.

Comment: Could you try adding the file again? It's a bit hard to read

Comment: this website does not parse the code properly. I comes so messy:( https://pastebin.pl/view/e944f92f

Comment: Could you provide your nuxt.config.js file?

Comment: Here it is : https://pastebin.pl/view/772f14ae

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212735/discussion-between-pinpiguin-and-hides).

Comment: Can you show where you're defining $axios? Did you create a global variable like Vue.prototype.$axios? Also, isn't it supposed to be this.$axios.get, where get does not have a $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not including the axios module, look at the installation process here https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup.html#install

Your config should then look like this in your export default

```
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],

  axios: {
    // proxyHeaders: false
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for [axios in Nuxt](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup.html#install)

1. Make sure axios is installed `npm install @nuxtjs/axios`
2. Add axios in nuxt.config.js

```
...
  axios: {
    // proxyHeaders: false
  }
...
```

3. You don't need the `$` in `$axios.$get`. It should be `$axios.get()`

Comment: @PinPiguin did you add in your code aswel? did you check all 3 steps?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/aurora10/amazone-clone/blob/master/admin/nuxt.config.js

Comment: @PinPiguin See my updated answer, you need to add it to your export default